# JMSException with hermesJms

Tags: jms, jndi, hermes-jms

Hello i have a error in Hermes jms when click on discover

this is error

```
javax.jms.JMSException: Could not create InitialContext: Failed to initialize JNDI context, tried 2 time or times totally, the interval of each time is 0ms. 
Timed out while attempting to establish connection to :t3://100.100.00.101:7002
    at hermes.JNDIContextFactory.createContext(JNDIContextFactory.java:282)
    at hermes.ext.HermesAdminSupport.discoverDestinationConfigs(HermesAdminSupport.java:441)
    at hermes.impl.HermesAdminAdapter.discoverDestinationConfigs(HermesAdminAdapter.java:82)
    at hermes.impl.DefaultHermesImpl.discoverDestinationConfigs(DefaultHermesImpl.java:1126)
    at hermes.browser.tasks.DiscoverDestinationsTask.invoke(DiscoverDestinationsTask.java:77)
    at hermes.browser.tasks.TaskSupport.run(TaskSupport.java:175)
    at hermes.browser.tasks.ThreadPool.run(ThreadPool.java:170)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

anyone can help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Not really a direct  answer to your question, but depending on your use cases, you could give a try to [JMSToolBox](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jmstoolbox/?source=directory)